# asp.net MVC return json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use $http request to call MVC controller and return data in JSON format. But i not able to get the result in javascript/angualr js. It return entire HTML page. Where i made the mistake?

```
myapp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.toggle = function () {
    $http({
        url: "/Admin/FilterMember",
        method: "GET",
        params: { id: $('#txtsearch').val() }
    }).then(function (result) {
        alert(result);
    });
};
}]);
```

Above is angular script in JS file.

```
public ActionResult FilterMember(string id)
{
    SqlParameter[] SqlParam = { new SqlParameter("@Filter", id) };
    DataTable dTable = MasterMindDB.dTableSP(DbConn, "SP_Get_MemberList", SqlParam);
    List<Member> member = new List<Member>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dTable.Rows)
    {
        member.Add(new Member
        {
            MemberName = row["Member ID"].ToString(),
            Email = row["Email"].ToString(),
            JoinDate = row["Join Date"].ToString(),
            Status = row["Status"].ToString()
        });
    }
    return View("Member", Json(member, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
}
```

Above is MVC controller

Comment: Just return `Json(member, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`

Answer (score 1):

This action is for the FilerMember view

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FilterMember () {
    return View();
}
```

This action will be called from the client side view. No need to return a `ViewResult`, just the data

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetMemberById(string id) {
    SqlParameter[] SqlParam = { new SqlParameter("@Filter", id) };
    DataTable dTable = MasterMindDB.dTableSP(DbConn, "SP_Get_MemberList", SqlParam);
    List<Member> member = new List<Member>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dTable.Rows) {
        member.Add(new Member {
            MemberName = row["Member ID"].ToString(),
            Email = row["Email"].ToString(),
            JoinDate = row["Join Date"].ToString(),
            Status = row["Status"].ToString()
        });
    }
    //Just return JsonResult.
    return Json(member, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Updated client

```
myapp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.toggle = function () {
    $http({
        url: "/Admin/GetMemberById",
        method: "GET",
        params: { id: $('#txtsearch').val() }
    }).then(function (result) {
        alert(result);
    });
};
}]);
```

Comment: I want return the View because i using Single page application concept. If remove the View, then my view wont render. Do you have any solution. Thx

Comment: ok then move the filter call to another action that is responsible for only returning the data.